Why do all browsers seem to support Webkit CSS prefixes?
I wanted to see and test firsthand how different browsers support different vendor specific prefixes (-webkit, -moz, -ms, -o).
And I was suprised to see that both Firefox and Safari support -webkit prefixes (or perhaps I'm misinterpreting something),
I saw that they supported -webkit-border-radius,
They even supported -webkit-text-stroke that does not have a -moz/-o prefix variant,
Moreover, they don't seem to support -o-border-radius and -moz-border-radius accordingly,
Firefox even shows a warning hint next to the disabled property saying that it is not supported in others browsers.
Are Firefox and Safari standarizing webkit properties usage?
Am I just missing something when I tested it?
In Which browsers support WebKit CSS? I saw that it was asked what browsers support webkit, but as some answers suggest there, Firefox is NOT listed as a browser that supports Webkit, and this still does not explain why both Firefox and Safari do not support they'e own vendor prefixes, again, unless I miss something.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .test {
                -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
                -webkit-text-stroke: 2px blue;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="test">Test</h1>
    </body>
</html>



vendor prefixes are not a standard. It doesn't mean that any property can be prefixed, some properties had only one or no prefix at all (I don't think -o-border-radius existed at any time)

WebKit is the name of Safari's engine, not Chrome's, If the -webkit prefix belonged to any of them, it would be Safari (and Epiphany). Use of the prefixes across engines is simply pragmatism. If authors widely use a prefixed property without a standard property alternative, then browsers benefit from supporting it.

WebKit is primarily supported and used by the Safari browser. I personally use caniuse.com to check cross-browser support for CSS syntax..
In your case, you can view a list of -webkit- CSS properties and their browser support here.
However, the best practice is to avoid vendor prefixes like -webkit-, -moz-, -ms-, and -o-, and instead use standard, unprefixed CSS whenever possible.
